# How can i execute a class with a separate load method?

Tags: python, function, class

What parameters should I pass to load a dataframe using this class?

```
class SafeLoadExcel:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file = file_name
        extension = Path(file_name).suffix
        if extension == '.csv':
            self.load_f = pd.read_csv
        elif extension == '.xlsx':
            self.load_f = pd.read_excel

    def load(self):
        try:
            df = self.load_f(self.file)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            df = self.load_f(self.file, encoding='iso-8859-1')
        return df
```

Comment: x = SafeLoadExcel('your_file_name_Here')  
x.load()

Comment: At the very least, `SafeLoadExcel` should probably be a class method. It's possible there's no reason to define a class here at all, but rather a regular function: `df = safe_load_excel("foo.csv")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only 2 methods on this class, you can get a `df` by

```
df = SafeLoadExcel("some/file/name.xlsx").load()
```

And that's a good hint that this should not have been a class in the first place. It would make as much sense to do

```
def safe_load_excel(file_name):
    extension = Path(file_name).suffix
    if extension == '.csv':
        load_f = pd.read_csv
    elif extension == '.xlsx':
        load_f = pd.read_excel
    else:
        raise ValueError("File must be csv or xlsx")
    try:
        return load_f(self.file)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return load_f(self.file, encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: Thank you, I am learning Python and very new to it, it would be really great if you could tell me when should I be defining class?

Comment: In this case, the class only does one thing that returns a single value. There is no reason to keep the instance around after it has finished its work. Making it a class just makes the code more complicated without a benefit to the consumer. In fact, it raises the exact question you asked - How do I use this thing? Exactly when to make a class is hotly debated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SafeLoadExcel` provides some other methods for working with the resulting data frame, I would define two separate class methods, and *maybe* a third that detects which of the first two to use depending on extension present in the file name. `SafeLoadExcel.__init__` itself is reserved for when you already *have* a dataframe, regardless of its original source.

```
class SafeLoadExcel:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    @classmethod
    def _from_file(cls, filename, reader):
        """Load a dataframe from a file.

           filename - name of file to read
           reader - a function to parse the file and return a dataframe
        """
        return cls(reader(filename, encoding='iso-8859-1'))

    # CSV-specific wrapper around _from_file
    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, filename):
        return cls._from_file(filename, pd.read_csv)

    # Excel-specific wrapper around _from_file
    @classmethod
    def from_excel(cls, filename):
        return cls._from_file(filename, pd.read_excel)

    # Not to be confused with the private method with a similar name.
    # Detect which public class method to use.
    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            f = cls.read_csv
        elif filename.endswith('.xslx'):
            f = cls.read_excel
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Cannot determine type of {filename}")

        return f(filename)
```

Then you can use

```
f1 = SafeLoadExcel.from_csv("foo.csv")
f2 = SafeLoadExcel.from_excel("foo.xlsx")

f3 = SafeLoadExcel.from_file("foo.csv")
f4 = SafeLoadExcel.from_file("foo.xlsx")
```

`f1` and `f3` should be effectively the same thing, as should be `f2` and `f4`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I am new to Python and just started learning. Could you please tell me the difference between @class method and function?